# Where to place API key for Google Geocoding API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

We use [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#Geocoding) to map address to Latitude and Longitude.

Here is the sample URL for encoding (which returns json) -

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Dallas&sensor=false

Message: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Ok, it makes sense, because we exceed over 2500 daily limit so we place API key like this -

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=xxxxx&address=Dallas&sensor=false

Message: REQUEST_DENIED

***I'm wondering where/how to place the API Key.***

Comment: Just to confirm, you have an API key for a business account - not a free key for using google maps api in general?

Comment: Added info from here to my answer: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside/

Comment: Just to articulate this, the developer console (API) key can only be used with the Google Maps client-side APIs.  The call you're making is to the Google Maps Geocoding web service API, hence the `REQUEST_DENIED` response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Direction APIs error: REQUEST_DENIED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46748233/google-direction-apis-error-request-denied)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like in version 3 you need to pass the `ClientID` in the URL and not a `key` as you do in the free version: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3#newkey

So your URL should look like: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?client=xxxxx&address=Dallas&sensor=false

Not lucky enough to have a paid account so I cannot test - but I think that will get you on the correct path.

Relevant from this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/

> Client ID
>
> You must include your client ID in all API requests. Your client ID
>   identifies you as a Maps API for Business customer and enables support
>   and purchased quota for your application. Requests made without a
>   client ID are not eligible for Maps API for Business benefits.
>
> If you're switching from the free API services to a Maps API for
>   Business implementation, you must remove the key parameter from your
>   requests. Google Maps API web services will deny requests made with
>   both a client ID and a key.
>
> More information is available in the Authentication and Authorization
>   chapter of this guide.
>
> If you have lost your client ID, you can recover it by logging in to
>   the support portal and clicking Maps: Add URLs from the links on the
>   left of the page.

**EDIT**

For more information, including instructions on passing your client ID to the Earth API, v2 API, and the Maps API for Flash, please read [Loading Client-side APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside/load).

If you have lost your client ID or cryptographic key, you can recover them by logging in to the [support portal](http://www.google.com/enterprise/portal) and clicking Maps: Add URLs from the links on the left of the page.

Comment: We just finished chatting with Google on the phone. Unfortunately, we did not have Business Account for Geocoding which costs ***$17,000*** per year. Now we are talking with our client. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: To avoid the limits you an cache results within your application's database - depends on what you are geocoding (addresses which are infrequently the same - which basically means you need to shell out, or common locations frequently reused, which means you only have to only call google's API for new ones).

Comment: Relevant: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15052/how-to-avoid-google-map-geocode-limit

Comment: @Matthew Can you please see this question it's regarding geocodr class api limitation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144432/is-there-any-difference-between-android-geocoder-class-and-google-geocoder-api