# Google Geolocation API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-geolocation

I am learning to use Google Geolocation API. I have got my key and I am just trying to make a simple form which takes the city name and returns me the latitude and longitude using Geolocation API.

The simple form is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<form>
    <fieldset>
        <ul>

            <li>
                <label for="city-search">City Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="city-search" placeholder="e.g. Rochester, NY">
            </li>

        </ul>

    </fieldset>

    <input type="button" id="sub" value="Submit" onclick="geolocation()">


</form>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="geolocation.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me how to use the Geolocation API in a way that I can retrieve the latitude and longitude of the entered city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daily limit without API Key is 2500. You can read my question - [Where to place API key for Google Geocoding API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410485/where-to-place-api-key-for-google-geocoding-api)

If you just use Geocoding on client browser, you do not need Google API Key. *You can still pass the key if your client is a heavy user and you want to pay on behalf of your client.*

Here is the working demo - https://jsfiddle.net/uj5qcqx0/

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sub').click(function() {
    var city = $('#city-search').val();
    if (city.length) {
      var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=" + city;
      $.get(url, function(data) {       
        $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(data));        
      });
    } else {
      alert("Please enter city.");
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="city-search">City Name</label>
<input type="text" id="city-search" placeholder="e.g. Rochester, NY">

<input type="button" id="sub" value="Submit">

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: so as of now, we are required to include an API for whatever request made, do you have any updated solution on this?

Comment: Also, I believe that the geolocation and geocoding are now separate feature that serves different purpose. (geolocation: locating user, geocoding: give coordinate based on address and vice versa)