# Google Direction APIs error: REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: google-maps, google-api, directions

We are developing and that needs the direction APIs to measure the distance between 2 addresses.
The only option I have is http as this part of the app doesn't have a map.

I am trying to understand the proper usage of the direction APIs, related Keys and quota.

First we were issuing the http call without a key.

maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=43.65077%2C-79.378425&destination=43.63881%2C-79.42745

Sometimes we get back the proper response, but many times I get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
(even though we are hardly issuing any calls, it is impossible that we are triggering any limit)

Then after visiting this link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits, we enabled the API key and added the key to the call.
So the call now looks like this

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=43.65077%2C-79.378425&destination=43.63881%2C-79.42745&key=AI***AQ

Every time, we issue the call, we get back REQUEST_DENIED

Comment: Why do you say "The only option I have is http as this part of the app doesn't have a map"?  The error message I get with your request (including a valid key) is "Requests to this API must be over SSL. Load the API with https: instead of http:".  You need to make the requests over https.

Comment: Can you confirm that Directions API is enabled in your project? Did you apply any restriction on the API key?

Comment: The issue was the fact that I was still using http after I added the key. Switching to https solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message I get with your request (including a valid key) is "Requests to this API must be over SSL. Load the API with https: instead of http:". You need to make the requests over https.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=43.65077%2C-79.378425&destination=43.63881%2C-79.42745&key=VALID_API_KEY
```

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you have enabled the following APIs

- Directions API
- Distance Matrix API
- Geocoding API
- Geolocation API
- Places API

In case its for Android, also enable the following

- Maps SDK for Android

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue use the https:// instead of http:// in your base url. I have been testing some items and got the same error message. Once I changed it to https:// I was able to make the call.

Hope this helps anyone else with this issue.